# Vlookup with variables

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use Vlookup in my vba that searches in another file that is chosen.  The vlookup I copied from recorded macro. I changed the name of Workbook and Worksheets because it is different every time. The range is the same. I got the error 438 “object doesn't support this property or method”.

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select BPM Report for previous month"
        .ButtonName = "OK"
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

        oldbpm = .SelectedItems.Item(1) End With
     Workbooks.Open oldbpm

Dim Sheetstarybpm As Worksheet 
Set Sheetstarybpm = ActiveSheet

Dim countrowsoldbpm1 As Long
    countrowsoldbpm1 = Range("a10", Range("a10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Workbooks("BPM-Tool.xlsm").Activate Worksheets("OU").Activate

Dim countrowsoldbpm As Long
    countrowsoldbpm = Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Range("D1:D1823").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'[" & oldbpm & "]" & Sheetstarybpm & "'!R10C2:R7000C101,100,FALSE),0)"
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & countrowsoldbpm)
```

Comment: Why do you have `B2` in your formula if you are using R1C1 notation?

Comment: Which line of code triggers the error? Also, `End With` needs to be in its own line, not "tacked on" at the end of ` oldbpm = .SelectedItems.Item(1)`.

Comment: I got the error by:
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'[" & oldbpm & "]" & Sheetstarybpm & "'!R10C2:R7000C101,100,FALSE),0)"

End with was just pasted wrongly. In my code it is ok.